# Struggling to see how I can authenticate into AWS from Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

I am trying to authenticate AWS into Jenkins using DefaultAWSCredentialsProvider but for some reason It never works!

```
AWSSecurityTokenService awsSecurityTokenService =       AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                 .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
                .withRegion(region)
                .build();
```

I tried using this

```
pipeline {
   agent {
    // Define agent details here
}
environment {
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID     = credentials('aws_access_key_id')
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = credentials('aws_secret_access_key')
}
```

when I try outputting it, I see this. I am not too familiar with Groovy and Jenkins.

- aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXX
  /workspace/_qa-new-gih_feature_jenkinstests@tmp/durable-49d31937/script.sh: 1: /workspace/_qa-new-gih_feature_jenkinstests@tmp/durable-49d31937/script.sh: aws_access_key_id: not found

I am sure I am missing something here, can some one please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aws-cli login method to authenticate,

you just need https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials-binding/ to use this **withCredentials** function, and this https://plugins.jenkins.io/aws-credentials/ AWS credentials plugin to create global or system credentials using **AccessKeyId** and **SecretAccessKey**.

Then use this snippet below in any of you stages steps in pipeline (recommended: first stage) so that you can authenticate your aws-cli for that pipeline instance.

NOTE: make sure you don't use MFA enabled account for this purpose, and have aws-cli preinstalled on your node template.

```golang
    stages {
        stage("aws-cli-login") {
            steps {
                withCredentials([[
                    $class: "AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding",
                    credentialsId: "your.aws.credentials",
                    accessKeyVariable: "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID",
                    secretKeyVariable: "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
                ]]) {
                    sh 'aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'
                    sh 'aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
                }
                sh "aws do something here or in any stage further"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using withAWS which kind of resolved this!

Comment: Yes, that's the similar option, just depends on use case.